# My visual report throws error, can't determine the relationship between two or more fields

Tags: powerbi, dax, data-modeling

I have a model where `cqm_detail` is connected with `detaildistinct` table with 1 to many relationship on `cqm_detail[issuenumber]` and `detaildistinct[issuenumber]`.

Also I have a table `detailhierarchy` joined to `detaildistinct` table with 1 to many relationship on `detaildistinct[issuenumber]` and `detailhierarchy[parentkey]`.

But when I try to create a visual report, taking `issueid` from `cqm_detail` and `parentkey` from `detailhierarchy`, it throws an error:

> Can’t display the data because powerbi can't determine the relationship between two or more fields.

Can anyone help me fetch `parentkey` for the `issueid`?

Comment: Can you post the visual relationship diagram?

Answer (score 1):

If your relationships are set up like this

```
cpm_detail[issuenumber]    : * <--- 1 : detaildistinct[issuenumber]
detailhierarchy[parentkey] : * <--- 1 : detaildistinct[issuenumber]
```

then `detailhierarchy` cannot filter `cpm_detail` since the relationship only activates in the 1-to-many direction.

To get it to work like you expect, you'll either need to make that second one bidirectional or else use the `CROSSFILTER` function in the relevant measure(s).

You could also use `detaildistinct[issuenumber]` in your visual instead of `detailhierarchy[parentkey]` but that's basically ignoring `detailhierarchy` entirely.